# Dropdown hamburger not working Jquery and JS CDN placement is correct

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am just trying to have the hamburger icon drop down the navbar when the screen is formatted to iphone size but it will not drop down.

I am also pretty sure that the JS and jquery placement is correct.

```
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Portfolio.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>   
        <!-- NAVBAR -->
            <nav id="myNavbar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collpase" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>

                        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">COTO</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a href="#header">Home</a></li>

                            <li><a href="#Services">Services</a></li>

                            <li><a href="#pricing">Pricing</a></li>

                            <li><a href="#Team">Team</a></li>

                            <li><a href="#Clients">Clients</a></li>

                            <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
         <!-- NAVBAR END -->    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Bootstrap (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/):

1. You have incorrect data-toggle attribute:

`data-toggle="collpase"` → `data-toggle="collapse"`

2. Change the navbar-toggle button's `data-target` attribute to ID selector instead of class selector:

`data-target=".navbar-collapse"` → `data-target="#navbar"`

3. Add the ID attribute to navbar:

`<div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar">`

Answer (score 0):

You had just a little typo at the `data-toggle` attribute. Also, you must always use ID selectors when you are trying to select a single element. Here is a working example (tested):

```
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Portfolio.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>   
        <!-- NAVBAR -->
            <nav id="myNavbar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNav">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>

                        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">COTO</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="myNav">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a href="#header">Home</a></li>

                            <li><a href="#Services">Services</a></li>

                            <li><a href="#pricing">Pricing</a></li>

                            <li><a href="#Team">Team</a></li>

                            <li><a href="#Clients">Clients</a></li>

                            <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
         <!-- NAVBAR END -->    
    </body>
    </html>
```